# Favorite functionality for my laravel application

Tags: laravel

I'm currently trying to make a favorite functionality to my laravel application. I'm trying to access the post table with eloquent, but it says property posts(the function in the favorite model) does not exist.

Update: I updated the query. If I dump $favorite I get two items, which is correct, but now I get this error message instead:Property [posts] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance. (View: C:\xampp\laravelprojects\Skakahand\resources\views\profile\index.blade.php)

```
<div class="favorite-section">
    <p>Mina favoriter</p>

    {{$favorite->posts->title}}

</div>
```

This is my controller:

```
public function index(User $user)
    {

        $favorite = Favorite::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
        ->get();

        return view('profile.index',[
            'user' => $user,
            'favorite' => $favorite

        ]);
    }
```

Favorite model:

```
class Favorite extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id'
    ];

    
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    } 
}
```

and post model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    /* use Sluggable; */
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'body',
        'category',
        'decision',
        'number',
        'place',
        'image_path',
        'slug',
        'price',
        'user_id',
    ];


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    
    public function favorites(){
        return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class);
    }


   
}
```

Comment: What do you get if you dump `$favorite`?

Comment: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#620 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: basically nothing

Comment: I changed the query to $favorite = Favorite::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id) Now I get two items but still this error message Property [posts] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance. (View: C:\xampp\laravelprojects\Skakahand\resources\views\profile\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First correct Model like this

```
class Favorite extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'post_id',
    ];


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }


    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

In controller change code like this for for avoid lazy loads

```
public function index(User $user)
{

    $favorites = Favorite::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
        ->with('post')
        ->get();

    return view('profile.index',[
        'user' => $user,
        'favorites' => $favorites

    ]);
}
```

in blade use code like

```
<div class="favorite-section">
    <p>Mina favoriter</p>
    
    <ul>
        
        @foreach($favorites as $favorite)
                
             <li>{{ $favorite->post->title ?? ''  }} </li>
           
        @endforeach
    
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: What was the root cause for this error message?  So I don't make the same mistake again, was it that I forgot post_id to fillable in the model?

Comment: post_id is not issue. I think your original question you are forget use in then end ->get() method.

Answer (score 0):

just include `->with()` for relationship,
your query should look like this

```
 $favorite = Favorite::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->with('post')
        ->get();

        return view('profile.index',compact('favorite','user'));
```